# What is a simple way to make "null" not to render?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have created a simple polymer element with no js that has attributes in it. When the attribute is not called it shows "null".

http://jsbin.com/wakal/1/

How do I tell the element not to show null?.  If the attribute is left blank I do not want anything to show up?

Comment: `if (/*object*/ != null) { /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: the way to declare [*default values*](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#default-property-values) is with the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally to use default values you need to use the script and initialize the properties there.

See http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#default-property-values

---

Alternatives are to use

- `{{propname?propname:'default value'}}` or
- `{{propname||'default'}}`